# Change name in Debian package of sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to attach sbt-native-packager to a root-aggregate of a project, but that root project has published name for Maven of `"foobar"`. I want the artifact generated through `debian:packageBin` to consistently use `"foo"` instead.

How do I accomplish this?

I tried

```
name           in Debian := "foo"
packageName    in Debian := "foo"
normalizedName in Debian := "foo"
executableScriptName := "foo"
artifact       in Debian := (artifact in Debian).value.copy(name = "foo")
```

etc. None has an effect. I end up having `etc/foobar` and `usr/share/foobar`.

---

**Edit**: After these settings I'm getting closer:

```
name                      in Debian := "foo"
normalizedName            in Debian := "foo"
packageName               in Debian := "foo"
name                      in Linux  := "foo"
normalizedName            in Linux  := "foo"
packageName               in Linux  := "foo"
```

The problem now is that the resulting `.deb` File contains every directory twice, i.g. `etc/foobar` vs `etc/foo`, `usr/share/foobar` vs `usr/share/foo`. So somewhere the old package name must be referenced still... This is odd, because I double checked that `linuxPackageMappings in Debian` only contains the correct files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the edit, you do have to override settings both for scope `Debian` and `Linux`. My mistake was that `target` will still be polluted by old files even if you delete the `.deb` file. So if you change these things, you must run a `rm -r target` before repackaging. The settings then are:

```
executableScriptName     := "foo"
name           in Debian := "Foo"
packageName    in Debian := "foo"
name           in Linux  := "Foo"
packageName    in Linux  := "foo"
packageSummary in Debian := "Description of Foo"
```

Comment: quick note: are the different Foo/foo capitalizations intentional?

Comment: Yes, I keep my application name in camel-case, whereas packages are (also by default) based on `normalizedName` which is the lower-case version. To be on the safe side, one could also override `normalizedName := "foo"` here.